# Strategy for finding active/inactive users in a period of time

Tags: php, mysql

I need to implement a mechanism with the following abilities:

- Add new users
- Delete a user
- Enable a user
- Disable a user

And also let the administrator to select a period of time and then show which users were:

- Available in the system at that period
- Enabled
- Disabled

The result should be for that exact period of time.

**Note:** A user might be enabled or disabled several times and I need to keep track of every single change. So, if the user is disabled between the March 1th and April 2nd, it should not be appear in the results if the administrator querying a time period between March 1th up to April 2nd, but it should be included in the results if the administrator querying any other period of time.

Also the tricky part is to contain the usesr who has been added, deleted, enabled or disabled before the period that administrator querying.

I don't have any set up for now, so I'm pretty up for any idea. Actually I'm thinking of a mechanism like a `log` which you can query that later, but it should be really fast because I need to use it in many places.

Also I prefer to do everything in a single MySQL Query, however the PHP combination/interaction is also okay.

Comment: And the question is...? Methinks look into Slowly Changing Dimensions and come back: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Comment: @Denis thanks for the input, I'm reading that right now ... :)

Comment: @Denis Thanks again, that was really helpful. I still didn't implement the solution, but I got the idea. Please resend your comment as an answer so I can choose it as an accepted answer. I'm sure it can help other people as well! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per commentary, look into Slowly Changing Dimensions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

An additional top, having implemented this a few times myself. Personally, I've found it better to have two sets of tables, rather than a single one.

Think of the main one as a normal table with an extra rev (for revision_id) field:

```
id, rev, field1, field2
```

rev is a foreign key to the revisions table:

```
id, rev, field1, field2, start_date, end_date
```

And if you ever use Postgres to implement it, I'd advise to look into the tsrange type instead of two separate start_date and end_date types.

The main table vs history tables makes "normal" queries perform better and much easier to index.

Comment: Thanks, it was really good to know about it. I thought I'm facing just a fancy problem which I need to finally refactor my structure, however I learned really good things out of that. Also thanks for the `tsrange`, as I'm working with geo data as well, I might finally move on to the Postgres as it seems it's better than MySQL in some (many?) situations. :)